# How to return a boolean if a string contains one of an array of substrings?

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, boolean, strpos

I'm struggling with a simple function that loops through an array and returns `true` only if it finds a given substring in one of the array's elements.

For some reason, I'm ALWAYS getting `false`... even when the `$email` parameter is contains one of the valid domains. Ex: `scoobydoo@domain1.com`.

```
function check_email($email) {
    $whitelist_domains = array(
        '@domain1.com',
        '@domain2.com',
        '@domain3.com'
    );
    $output = FALSE;
    foreach ($whitelist_domains as $domain) {   
        $pos = strpos( $email, $domain ); 
        if ( $pos ) {
            $output = TRUE;
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: strpos may return 0, which is == false; use if($pos !== false) instead

Comment: You need to do a strict comparison on `$pos` because if it finds it at the start of the string your test will fail because `$pos = 0`. Do `if($pos === false)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not breaking the loop if you find the domain, so what you are getting is actually the result for the LAST string checked only.
just add `break;` after `$output = TRUE;`

Comment: BTW there are way more efficient ways of doing that, check out preg_match. you can do it without a loop.

Comment: Boom! That was it. When I first wrote the function I was using `return TRUE` inside the loop (I think a `return` escapes the loop, right?).

I was going to do preg_match, but the regex syntax always makes my head hurt a little. For a short array, does it make much of a performance difference?

Comment: I don't usually geek-out on this kind of stuff, but I did some research based on your suggestion (use preg_match) and I was surprised to find this article... 

http://lzone.de/articles/php-string-search.htm

...claiming that strpos() is actually faster than preg_match().

Comment: It depends on the use case. strpos is faster, but PHP loops are slow. Write a comparison benchmark, and post the results if you do!

Comment: I'm interested in your idea, but I'm not clear how to avoid the loop. Are you suggesting there's a way to preg_match the entire array?

Comment: if the number of domains is reasonable, you can do something like: `preg_match("/(domain1\\.com|domain2\\.com|...)$/", $email);`. but actually the fastest approach would be to keep a dictionary like `array('domain1.com' => true, 'domain2.com' => true, ...);` which has an O(1) hash table, and then just separate the email's domain and check `if ($domains[$email_domain] == true) { ... }`. This should be SUPER fast compared to anything else.

Comment: Ahh. Now we're talking. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the official doc of [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

And make sure to add a break after you set `$output` to true.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good function to use the `===` operator with as it makes sure the value and type are equal (`1==true`, but `1!==true`)

```
if (strpos( $email, $domain )!==false) {
    $output = TRUE;
}
```

Comment: if strpos returns 7, will (strpos === true) be true?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if ( $pos ) {
```

to

```
if ( $pos !== false) {
```

this is because is strpos returns 0, that will equate to false, even though the string was found.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two direct/common methods that have different advantages:

**Method #1**: non-regex approach

```
function check_email1($email){
    $whitelist_domains=['@domain1.com','@domain2.com','@domain3.com'];
    foreach($whitelist_domains as $domain){
        if(strpos($email,$domain)!==false){
            return true;  // allow quick return (exit loop & function asap)
        }
    }
    return false;  // default response
}
```

**Method #2**: regex approach

```
function check_email2($email){
    $whitelist_pattern='/@(?:domain1\.com|domain2\.com|domain3\.com)$/';  // condense if possible /@domain[123]\.com$/
    return (bool)preg_match($whitelist_pattern,$email);  // convert 0 or 1 output to boolean (false/true)
}
```

[Demo Link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f62c1e4cd7dde731ec5c43dbdd99e5cbb17cb85)

**Input / Function Call**:

```
$emails=['user@domain1.com','bad@bad.com'];
foreach($emails as $email){
    echo "$email\n";
    var_export(check_email1($email));
    echo "\n";
    var_export(check_email2($email));
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

**Output**:

```
user@domain1.com
true
true

bad@bad.com
false
false
```

**Advantages/Disadvantages**:

- [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) in the majority of situations will outperform regex functions.  Your default method should be to use string functions and only change to regex when string functions are less efficient or too convoluted to code.  A related page: [Which is more efficient, PHP string functions or regex in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634676/which-is-more-efficient-php-string-functions-or-regex-in-php)
- Looping `$whitelist_domains` in #1 makes for a clunkier looking code block compared to #2 (which can be condensed to a one-liner if you write the pattern directly into [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)).
- Simple/common mistakes sometimes occur when dealing with `strpos()`.  These mistakes may include:

  - not checking for `false` in the `if` condition
  - writing the `haystack` and `needle` in the wrong order
- #2 does require some knowledge about regex (escaping, character classes, alternatives, etc.) which can be a deterrent for inexperienced coders.  Depending on how you write your regex pattern and how many domains will be whitelisted, #2 is likely to be harder to maintain than #1.
- #2 has the added benefit of being able to check that the `domain.com` substring appears at the end of the word via the `$` metacharacter.  For this reason, regex offers stronger validation.

Answer (score 0):

## You should change your code in this:

```
function check_email($email) {
    $whitelist_domains = array(
        '@domain1.com',
        '@domain2.com',
        '@domain3.com'
    );

    foreach ($whitelist_domains as $domain) {   
        if ( strpos( $email, $domain ) !== false ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

## Documentation of `strpos`

Quoting from the manual (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

> The !== operator can also be used.  Using != would not work as expected
>   because the position of 'a' is 0. The statement (0 != false) evaluates
>   to false.

#### Example code

```
<?php
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

// The !== operator can also be used.  Using != would not work as expected
// because the position of 'a' is 0. The statement (0 != false) evaluates 
// to false.
if ($pos !== false) {
     echo "The string '$findme' was found in the string '$mystring'";
         echo " and exists at position $pos";
} else {
     echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the string '$mystring'";
}
?>
```