# How can I filter my e-mails faster in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, email, filter

I am currently writing a script to filter some e-mail contents I've received.

These e-mails are replies to my newsletter campaign, I would like to know who wants to be unsubscribed. For that, I can seek some specific words such as "please", "remove", and I also have to check if the e-mail was sent from a mailer-daemon so I can alert the user to change his e-mail address next time he logs in.

First, I have to retrieve the dictionnary from a MySQL database, it contains 77 words at the moment, then I call two preg_match_all function for each word in each mail I process.

I want to check if the entire word `\bplease\b` can be seen inside the e-mail content, and some people can make a mistake and write the word as "pleease", then I use `\bp+l+e+a+s+e+\b` after that.

But the dictionnary is growing up, more and more words are added inside, and the script is getting slower, it's processing at least 4 emails per second.

Do you have any other way to process the mails faster than now ?

Would it be faster to build a regex matching 77 words instead of executing 77 preg_match_all commands ?

Comment: Wouldn't be fair to provide an link for them to auto-unsubscribe?

Comment: I already do, but a lot of people don't click on it, and I also want to fetch mails coming from mailer daemons

Comment: I guess you could do this, but it's standard practice to send the emails from a noReply@myDomain.com and then include an unsubscribe link at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your question, "Would it be faster to build a regex matching 77 words instead of executing 77 preg_match_all commands ?," I recommend not using a regex at all.  I could be wrong, but I think string functions are faster than regex.  Read this: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?190485-performance-doubts-regex-vs-string-functions-using-this-and-1-more-doubt!-plz!-)  Also read this [Which is more efficient, PHP string functions or regex in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634676/which-is-more-efficient-php-string-functions-or-regex-in-php)

Comment: Alright, I'll finally write some functions to check the words character per character, thanks for your advice !