# Why isn't my url encoding working?

Tags: php, regex

Please forgive me if this question appears too cheap.

I have this line:

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $_GET['id'], $arr);
```

When you pass a value with space during a search, the value breaks once a space is encountered.

For instance:

```
36 2543541284
```

Notice a space between 6 and 2. In a situation similar to this, only 36 is displayed.

The reminder of digits after space are ignored. This is giving users, "no data found" message.

I have tried using urlencode to add 20% but no luck.

```
preg_match_all($pattern, rawurlencode($_GET[id]), $arr);
```

I have also tried urlencode but to no avail.

What am I possibly doing wrong?

```
function format($matches)
{
    return $matches[1][0].(strlen($matches[2][0])>0?$matches[2][0]:" ").$matches[3][0].(strlen($matches[4][0])>0?"  ".$matches[4][0]:"");
}

// CONSTRUCT A REGULAR EXPRESSION
$pattern
= '/'         // regex delimiter
. '('         // START of a capture group
. '\d{2}'     // exactly two digits
. ')'         // END of capture group
. '('         // START SECOND capture group
. '[ND]?'     // letters "D" OR "N" in any order or number - This is optional
. ')'         // END SECOND capture group
. '('         // START THIRD capture group
. '\d*'       // any number of digits
. ')'         // END THIRD capture group
. '('         // START FOURTH capture group
. 'GG'        // the letters "GG" EXACTLY
. '[\d]*'     // any number of digits
. ')'         // END THIRD capture group
. '?'         // make the LAST capture group OPTIONAL
. '/'         // regex delimiter
;


 preg_match_all($pattern, rawurlencode($_GET[id]), $arr);

// REFORMAT the array
$str = format($arr);

// show what we did to the data
echo '<pre>' . PHP_EOL;
echo '1...5...10...15...20...' . PHP_EOL;
echo $pattern;
echo PHP_EOL;
//Are we getting what we asked for? This is a test. We will comment out all 6 lines if we are happy with output of our REFORMATTING.
echo $str;
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: What's inside `$pattern` ? And does `36 2543541284` the value inside `$_GET['id']` ?

Comment: I'd add a space in the pattern.

Comment: hi @jOk and M42, I have updated code above to show the pattern and what it is intended to do. We defined some rules such as any ID where all the values are digits, should have a space after the 2nd digit. EG this value 362543541284 should have a space between 2nd digit and 3rd digit. Also, any digit that has GG on it, should have a space before the GG. EG, 36254354 GG1284

Problem, as stated is that when you enter 36 2543541284 into a search box, it accepts 36 and ignores everything after the space. There are more issues that I will post later if I can't resolve them on my own.

Comment: Your regex as it stands will not match two digits followed by a space and then further digits. If you want it to, you could change `[ND]?` to `[\sND]?`, although this would also allow a space if the string wasn't all digits. You need to specify the rules precisely for help with the regex.

Comment: @MikeM but it is matching two digits. It is also creating the single space if all values are digits. It is also creating 2 spacess before GG if there are GG letters in any of the values. The issue is that the spaces are breaking the value which is giving incorrect results and we would want to show the spaces when users search with those IDs. If the digit has N or D but no GG, then no spaces should be created. We want the spaces as specified by the rules but we also don't want spaces breaking the values. Is it what urlencode is supposed to do in php?

Comment: Updated my comment. It will match two digits, but not two digits followed by a space and then further digits. There is no provision for a space in your regex, so the digits after the space will not be captured.

Comment: @MikeM, you are absolutely correct. Adding [\sND] per your suggestion worked. Thank you very much sir. I do have one more question and I will post in a minute. If you could help, that would be greatly appreciated even more. Maybe, with this change, we may not have any issues now. We will see shortly after testing.

Please give a way to give you credit for solving this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex as it stands will not match two digits followed by a space and further digits.
If you want it to, you could change `[ND]?` to `[\sND]?`, although this would also allow a space if the string wasn't all digits.

You need to specify the rules precisely if you want further advice on the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is an overkill in this case.

**From the [urlencode manual](http://php.net/urlencode):**

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except `-_.`
>   have been replaced with a percent (`%`) sign followed by two hex digits
>   and spaces encoded as plus (`+`) signs. It is encoded the same way that
>   the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type. This differs from the [»
>   RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986) encoding (**see [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode)) in that for historical reasons,
>   spaces are encoded as plus (`+`) signs**.

It clearly states that if you want spaces to be encoded as `%20`, and not `+`, you should use [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode).

**Code example:**

```
$strings = array(
    '36 2543541284',
    '1234 5678',
    'this is a string'
);
$strings_encoded = array();

foreach($strings as $string)
{
    $strings_encoded[] = rawurlencode($string);
}

var_dump($strings_encoded);
```

**Outputs:**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "36%202543541284"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "1234%205678"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "this%20is%20a%20string"
}
```

Comment: I understand why your answer describes url encodings, as that is the subject of the OP's question and he may find the information useful. But the actual issue is that the regex wasn't matching the input strings correctly regardless of how the spaces were encoded - whether as `+` or `%20` or left simply as whitespace. Your 'overkill' comment does not make sense in this context.

Comment: @MikeM OP was obviously looking for an easier way out, hence his comment on having tried urlencode already (**From OP: I have also tried urlencode but to no avail.**). My answer is very much relevant. His goal is to encode a URL, and I posted the easiest way.

Comment: @thordarson, sorry good people. I didn't know that we still have conversations going on about the post. Both of you have really good points. Initially, I was looking for url encode that would add something like %20 to a space. However, even that didn't solve my problem when I did it manually. Truth is that the goal was to have a single space after first 2 digits and Mike's solution of adding \s to ND provided that solution. I am still having issues though as something still isn't right. I will post shortly. Thanks to all of your for your kindness at StackOverflow forum.

Comment: @Kenny Do you know the format of the string beforehand? Because if you do, there are a lot of ways to achieve what you're describing without resorting to regex, which is generally [slower than PHP's native functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634676/which-is-more-efficient-php-string-functions-or-regex-in-php).