# Get first letters from a string of two words (PHP - fastest way)

Tags: php, string

If I have a set of two words (separated by space), for example:

```
$str='nice couple';
```

What is the fastest (for server processing) method of getting the FIRST letters from each word? Ie. the final result should be:

> nc

I know I could take $str[0] and it would be the fastest to get the first character ('n), but how to get the second ('c') in such a fast way too so that I get in final 'nc'?

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far and where do you think that is slow?

Comment: You might look at the PHP manual for EXPLODE:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: As @bub said, what have you tried? im sure there are multiple ways.

Comment: $str[0] and strpos I tried. I also thought about reversing the second word and cutting the first and last character from string but it doesn't seem fast.

Comment: Btw - please reward the best answer rather than to vote on the repetitive question 'what have you tried' - it's not fair to those who actually help. Thank you.

Comment: [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok) instead of yucky `explode`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First get the words separated by space, then get the first character.

```
<?php
$str = 'nice couple';
$words = explode(' ', $str);
$result = $words[0][0]. $words[1][0];
echo $result;
```

As for the performance, the other way would be using a regular expression, but as it was discussed in this thread:

[Which is more efficient, PHP string functions or regex in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634676/which-is-more-efficient-php-string-functions-or-regex-in-php)

The best and fastest way to do simple operations are with standard functions.

---

Update on Halcyon response

Halcyon is right. I have made a test to check which of the solutions is faster:

```
<?php

function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

function solution1($text)
{
    for($i=1; $i<1000000; $i++) {
        $str = "nice couple";
        $pos = strpos($str, " ");
        $result = $str[0] . $str[$pos + 1];
    }
}

function solution2($text)
{
    for($i=1; $i<1000000; $i++) {
        $str = 'nice couple';
        $words = explode(' ', $str);
        $result = $words[0][0]. $words[1][0];
    }
}

$text = 'Administration\Controller\UserController::Save';

$time_start = microtime_float();

solution1($text);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did solution1 in $time seconds.\n";

$time_start = microtime_float();

solution2($text);

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;

echo "Did solution2 in $time seconds.\n";
```

And for 1000000 iterations, my solution doubles time:

Did solution1 in 0.61092305183411 seconds.
Did solution2 in 1.0136380195618 seconds.

So Halcyon proposal is faster:

```
$str = "nice couple";
$pos = strpos($str, " ");
$result = $str[0] . $str[$pos + 1];
```

Comment: You need to explain why this is the fastest (for server processing) method

Comment: I've considered regexp function, but for me, this must be the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I belive to be the fastest method:

```
$str = "nice couple";
$pos = strpos($str, " ");
$result = $str[0] . $str[$pos + 1];
```

It's faster than using an explode because explode does extra work that you don't need. This is reflected in a simple benchmark.

For 1,000,000 iterations explode is roughly 500ms slower. This also shows though that it doesn't really matter which approach you use unless your input is really really large.

---

If you absolutely wanted to go nuts here you could do an educated search for the space character, starting in the middle and rippling out - assuming that the space character is expected to be in the middle. I don't know if this is acutally faster (main bottleneck is probably the speed of `$str[$index]`) but conceptually it seems faster. `strpos` is a native function though it might run circles around anything you can do in PHP.

If you know something about the distribution of the words - for instance that the first word is always longer than the last - you could skew the search and get faster times (like use `strrpos` which searches backwards).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a longer string, you can perhaps use a foreach based solution.

Something like this :-

```
    $str='nice couple wed today';
    $strA = explode(' ', $str);
    $string = "";
    foreach($strA as $words)
    {
        $string = $string . $words[0];
    }
var_dump($string);
```

Comment: slightly cleaner syntax might be: `$string .= $words[0];`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how are you doing the profiling, But you may try this out:

```
<?php

        $string = "nice couple";
        $pos = strpos($string," ") + 1;
        echo $string[0].$string[$pos];
?>
```