# remove characters before and after

Tags: php, regex, substr, strstr

Here, I am using `strstr` to remove after characters and `substr` is used to remove before character. But how to remove all characters before and after at once ?

I need to get only `80` from this variable `$mrk = 'Science-80_John'` omitting `Science` and `John`.

What I am doing

```
$mrk = 'Science-80_John';

$mark = substr($mrk,strpos($mrk,'-')+1);
//output: 80_John

echo strstr($mark, '_', true);
//output: 80
```

Any other short or best way ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since op asked for a *short* or *best* way. Number_from_string *might perform* better using a cast. Ignoring `minus signs` (which could be hyphens in this example), we get a positive integer.

```
>>> $mrk = 'Science-80_John';
=> "Science-80_John"
>>> $num = (int)strpbrk ($mrk, "0123456789");
=> 80
```

The above use case assumes, besides only extracting one positive integer, that `scientific notation` is OK. John has decided to be a clever lad and change his signature to a very large number. We'd have to decide under what circumstances the system should accept or reject `scientific notation`.

```
>>> $mrk = 'Science-80E+21_John45';
>>> $num = (int)strpbrk ($mrk, "0123456789");
=> 9223372036854775807 // ack!

>>> $pat = "0123456789";
>>> $num = strpbrk ($mrk, $pat);
>>> $num = substr($num,0 ,strspn($num, $pat));
=>  "80"
```

Since the new return value consists of digits, we don't strictly need the cast anymore because of PHP's [type juggling](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). If there are no numbers at all, this solution returns the empty string, `""` which will generate an error if used in calculations later. Casting to `(int)` would silently return `0` but not tell us if the database needs correction. Which would work better in this situation? Another design decision.

String functions also avoid potential pitfalls with regex in some solutions from [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string). What happens if there is an extra "45" in $str? The result, `8045` is probably not desirable.

```
>>> $mrk = 'Science-80_John45';
=> "Science-80_John45"
>>> $newStr = preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $mrk);
=> "8045"
```

Comment: Great ! better than regex !!

Comment: Note that if somebody later views this answer and needs negative numbers, they'll have to add the `-` character to the `strpbrk` pattern. Here, that would not work because there is no easy way to distinguish between `minus signs` and hyphens. We'll leave that for another time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in `preg_replace()` and remove add non-digit characters

```
$mrk = 'Science-80_John';
$newStr = preg_replace("/\D+/", "", $mrk);
// 80
```

Comment: What about performance. Is it best to use regex or the previous way `substr` and `strstr`. Can you share the idea ?

Comment: In this case using string function is better than regex. Check [Which is more efficient, PHP string functions or regex in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634676/which-is-more-efficient-php-string-functions-or-regex-in-php)